# 404 Not found on C# WebApi

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-web-api2

I have an class that inherits from `ApiController`, some of its methods are called properly, some others are `Not found`. I can't find out why. I've been looking for a solution for hours now, still not getting it. Note That I'm new at this, it's my first WebApi in C#.

Routing: (WebApiConfig.cs)

```
public static class WebApiConfig
    {
        public static void Register(HttpConfiguration config)
        {
            // Configuration et services API Web

            // Itinéraires de l'API Web
            config.MapHttpAttributeRoutes();

            config.Routes.MapHttpRoute(
                name: "DefaultApi",
                routeTemplate: "api/{controller}/{action}/{id}",
                defaults: new { id = RouteParameter.Optional }
            );
        }
    }
```

Controller:

```
public class ExchangeController : ApiController
{
    public HttpResponseMessage GetMailHeader(int id)
    {
        Console.WriteLine(id);
        HttpResponseMessage response = new HttpResponseMessage();

        response.Content = new StringContent("ok");

        return response;
    }

    public HttpResponseMessage GetTest()
    {
        HttpResponseMessage response = new HttpResponseMessage();

        response.Content = new StringContent("working !!");

        return response;
    }
}
```

JS:

```
$.ajax({
    type: "GET",
    url: "/api/exchange/getTest",
    done: function (data) {
        console.log(data);
    }
});

$.ajax({
    type: "GET",
    url: "/api/exchange/getMailHeader",
    data: "42",
    done: function (data) {
        console.log(data);
    }
});
```

The `getTest` method returns a `200 OK` while the `getMailHeader` returns `404 Not Found`. What did I miss ?

Comment: Trivial step but I found myself stumbled in it: rebuild all solution then deploy again.

Comment: the data is incorrect for getMailHeader. you should do it like so: data: { id: 42 } (pass it as a JSON)

Comment: @Ahmedilyas This actually was part of the problem, it has led me to the solution ! ;)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks to everyone for your comments and answers, it has led me to the solution.

I was miss writing my `ajax` request. I didn't get any printed data on the console from `console.log`, and as @Ahmedilyas said, the `data` property was badly written.

The following works :

```
$.ajax({
    type: "GET",
    url: "/api/exchange/getTest"
})
.done(function (data) {
    console.log(data);
});

$.ajax({
    type: "GET",
    url: "/api/exchange/getMailHeader",
    data: { id: 42 }
})
.done(function (data) {
    console.log(data);
});
```

Answer (score 3):

As I understand it, data adds a query string, not a part of the url itself.  You define the id to be part of the url, so the right url is /api/exchange/getmailheader/42.
You can also move id out of the routeTemplate.

Comment: I've kept the `{id}` of the route because I don't know how to send extra data to the url any other way when I'm doing a `GET` method. Though I might just remove it if I can send all the data I need from the ajax `data`  property.

Answer (score 0):

Because your method starts with 'Get', and does not have a specific attribute, the framework assumes its an `HttpGet` (see rule 2 below), which requires the `id` to be part of the url (based on the default route).

If you want it to be an `HttpPost` (where you pass a json object in the body like you are doing now), then add a `[HttpPost]` attribute above your method or remove the 'Get' portion of the action name

[Reference](http://www.asp.net/web-api/overview/web-api-routing-and-actions/routing-and-action-selection)

> HTTP Methods. The framework only chooses actions that match the
>   HTTP method of the request, determined as follows:
>
> 1. You can specify the HTTP method with an attribute: AcceptVerbs,
>      HttpDelete, HttpGet, HttpHead, HttpOptions, HttpPatch, HttpPost, or
>      HttpPut.
> 2. Otherwise, if the name of the controller method starts with "Get", "Post", "Put", "Delete", "Head", "Options", or "Patch", then
>      by convention the action supports that HTTP method.
> 3. If none of the above, the method supports POST.